# Design of temporary data storage

Tags: database-design, architecture

I have a web scraping application. Users initiate 'reports' - what data points they would like to scrape. The data points can be as few as 1 or as large as 100K data points. There are many users initiating these reports. There are multiple crawling servers crawling the data points. Those data points are then sent to the central server(s). The central servers collect all the data points and when all (sufficient) data points for a report are collected, the report (excel) is generated and delivered to the client.

Now we need a data store to store the individual data points as they are crawled. Then when crawling is finished we need to query all these data points and build the report. The report is the end product and once the report is generated we need not store the crawled data; not at least for the purpose of servicing client needs. Side note: the crawled data is archived into a data warehouse.

Currently we use SQL for storing these crawling data points as the crawling is in progress. Process is: Dump all crwaling data into SQL --> When crawling is finished, which can take like as long as few hours, read back the crawl data belonging to report from SQL --> Purge the SQL regularly, like purge older than x days of data. The SQL server is running into scalability issues - too  many crawling data points. We get some 100M data points per day; each record of few KB. So that is about 400 GB data per day.

So we were exploring several alternatives and it would be helpful to get some comments on these:

1. Store crawl data in a local CSV file. When crawl is finished, read
   back the CSV file to generate the report. Downside is that it
   creates a single point of failure; the server on which the crawl
   data is stored may go down and take the already crawled data with
   it.
2. Replace SQL with one of the Big Data technologies; store crawl data into one of the following

   - AWS RedShift: querying for report data is easy when generating report. I am leaning towards this.
   - Big Table: Inserts are easy; but given that it is a key-value store,
     how easy would it be to get the 100K or so individual records back
     from DB when it is time to generate the report?
   - DynamoDB
3. Store crawl data into a file in some file server

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in Cassandra and then ETL the data to Redshift and build the reporting application against Redshift. This way you ensure that there is no single point of failure while ingesting the data and also you will have the flexibility of formatting or transposing the data through ETL.

Thanks,
Jayadeep